# Is there any concise expression for love between a man and a woman?

Tags: expressions

Love may be understood as the strong feeling between a man and a woman, as in the case of Romeo and Juliet, but it can also be interpreted as the feeling between a man and another man, or a man to an animal, or parents to their kids, etc, if I  want no misunderstanding and an exact meaning, is there any alternative expression which is not too wordy? Can "erotic love" serve the purpose?

Comment: "Erotic" describes a physical relationship, not an emotional one, although _Éros_ is more complex and nuanced in the original **[Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love)**. The closest you will come in English is **[romantic love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_(love))**, probably. By the way: there is no difference at all between the feelings of romantic love between a man and a man, between a woman and a woman, between a woman and a man, nor between _any_ of the "genders"

Comment: You'd probably want to be specific and call it "heterosexual love" ... but drawing that distinction can be misinterpreted as disapproval.